# How to show phone icon when a phone number text is selected?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SelectableText` Widget with a string which is a phone number

- Starts with `+`
- Has 12 digits

When the text is selected, the option to call it doesn't appear.
If I open the same text for example in a google search as below, I can see the option to call it. How can I make that in Flutter?

[image: How it should be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by looking at the example pointed out by @Luis Utrera

Solution:

```
  contextMenuBuilder: (context, EditableTextState editableTextState) {
    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar(
      anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.call),
            onPressed: () {
              // TODO: launch call app
            },
          ),
        ),
        ...editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems
            .map((ContextMenuButtonItem buttonItem) {
              return CupertinoButton(
                borderRadius: null,
                onPressed: buttonItem.onPressed,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                pressedOpacity: 0.7,
                child: Text(
                  CupertinoTextSelectionToolbarButton.getButtonLabel(
                    context,
                    buttonItem,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })
            .toList()
            .cast(),
      ],
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `contextMenuBuilder` property for this.
It will help you creating a different context menu depending on the current state of the user's selection:
More info: see `contextMenuBuilder` property in [SelectableText widget doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html)

```dart
SelectableText(
  'data to show',
  contextMenuBuilder: (_, textState) => Row(
    children: [
      if (isPhoneNumber(textState.textEditingValue.text))
        Container(), //Widget to make the phone call here
    ],
  ),
),

bool isPhoneNumber(String selection) {
  if (!selection.startsWith('+')) return false;
  return RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(selection.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: This way, I am able to show an Icon, however, it removes the Copy and Paste buttons. I guess this is fine since I don't need to copy it if I can call it, but how do I position it EXACTLY above/under the text (it has to be able to be both depending on the viewport), right now it gets positioned somewhere in the middle of the screen nowhere close to the text

Comment: @Miro maybe these examples will help you: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/contextMenuBuilder.html

Comment: Hi @Luis Utrera, your answer didn't, your comment pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Miro fair enough. I'm glad it helped!